# PLSQL calculate per group

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table which contains every order for all suppliers. I have the following query calculating the total quantity ordered for each supplier filtered on different date parameters.

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT SUM(ORDER_QTY)
        FROM  MY_TABLE
        WHERE  DELIVERY_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    ) AS YTD,
    (
        SELECT SUM(ORDERQTY)
        FROM   MY_TABLE
        WHERE  STATE = 'CONFIRMED'
        OR     STATE = 'RELEASED'
        AND    DELIVERY_DATE >= SYSDATE
    ) AS OVERDUE,
    SUPPLIER,
    SUPPLIER_NO 
FROM MY_TABLE 
GROUP  BY SUPPLIER
```

The query is returning the sum for all suppliers (i.e. the same number in each line) instead of the individual sum for each supplier. I am new to PLSQL and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is that the subqueries do not *correlate* the the outer query (typically, there should be a filter on the supplier number). Also, there is a mix of `AND` and `OR` in one of the `WHERE` clause that probably does not do what you want.

Bottom line, based on your problem statement, I think you don't want subqueries, but conditional aggregation. Something like:

```
SELECT SUPPLIER_NO, SUPPLIER,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN DELIVERY_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
            THEN ORDER_QTY 
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) as YTD,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN STATE IN ('CONFIRMED', 'RELEASED') AND DELIVERY_DATE >= SYSDATE 
            THEN ORDER_QTY 
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) as OVERDUE
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY SUPPLIER_NO, SUPPLIER
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also prefer the conditional aggregation approach as better (see answer from GMB) but here is a correlated query approach:

```
SELECT 
    T1.SUPPLIER_NO,
    T1.SUPPLIER,
(SELECT 
    SUM(ORDER_QTY)
    FROM  MY_TABLE T2 
    WHERE  
        T2.SUPPLIER_NO = T1.SUPPLIER_NO
        AND DELIVERY_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)) AS YTD,
(SELECT 
    SUM(ORDERQTY)
    FROM MY_TABLE T3
    WHERE  
        T3.SUPPLIER_NO = T1.SUPPLIER_NO
        AND (STATE = 'CONFIRMED' OR STATE = 'RELEASED')
        AND    DELIVERY_DATE >= SYSDATE) AS OVERDUE,
FROM 
    MY_TABLE T1
```